# AJAX loading image is not coming

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

When my AJAX is calling, my loading spinner is not coming. What mistake have I done?

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "one.html",
     contentType: "text/xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     data: "",
     beforeSend: function () {
        $.mobile.loading('show', {
           text: "Loading...",
           textVisible: true,
           theme: "a",
           textonly: false,
           html: ""
        });
     },
      complete: function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
     },
      crossDomain:true,
     success: function (data) { 
         alert("success");
     },
     error: function (data){
        alert("error");
     }
   });
```

I even used this code also, but it is also not working:

```
 $(document).on({
          ajaxStart: function () {      
          $.mobile.loading('show', {
             text: "Loading...",
             textVisible: true,
             theme: "d",
             textonly: false,
             html: ""
          });
          },
              ajaxStop: function () {     
              $.mobile.loading('hide');
          }
    });
```

Comment: any kind of errors? have you checkd that the beforeSend event is called (using alert or something)? the html is set to "", is it maybe displayed but has no visible content? does the loading box work if you call it outside the ajax call (i.e. on a click event)? have you in anyway tried to solve your problem yourself?

Comment: @x4rf41 no error msg is showin my prgram is running but only loading symbol is not cuming

Comment: @x4rf41 using click event i doesnt tried